# Adding third library to Sencha touch project

Tags: sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.3, pdfobject

I need to add a third library in a Sencha Touch project at the moment I am adding the link to the third library as `<script type="text/javascript" src="ux/utility/pdfobject_source.js"></script>`

But after the "sencha app build" command I have an error, console sends an error "PDFObject is not defined"

I think I am not adding correctly this library, but I don´t know how to..

Thanks!

EDIT and solved!

For this purpose I added the url to  the index.html, but its very IMPORTANT to add to the app.json the dependency... now its solved and I am glad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved...For this purpose I added the url to the index.html, but its very IMPORTANT to add to the app.json the dependency... now I am glad!

Answer (score 1):

you have to add js file referance in the app.json then only i will present after build:
        do like this in js section in app.json:

```
         {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
```